# Cannot load data from spreadsheet properly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spreadsheet looking like this:

[image: |Symbol | Name | |A |]

I'm trying to read it into dataframe:

```
def loading_nasdaq_info_from_spreadsheet():
    excel_file = 'nasdaq.xlsx'
    nasdaq_info_dataframe = pandas.read_excel(excel_file, index_col=0)
    # data cleaning
    nasdaq_info_dataframe.dropna()

    return nasdaq_info_dataframe


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = loading_nasdaq_info_from_spreadsheet()
    print(df.loc['symbol'])
```

I constantly get

> "raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'Symbol'"

It doesn't matter which key I wanna print or use. It is always the same error. What's even worse, even I manually (in excel) set everything to text, when I'm trying to

```
nasdaq_info_dataframe.applymap(lambda text: text.strip())
```

I get

> 'float' doesn't have strip()

I fight with this for a few hours now, so please help me.

EDIT:

Printing

```
print(df.loc)
```

gives

> <pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer object at 0x1160e8778>

Printing

print(df.columns)

gives

> Index(['Name', 'Sector', 'Industry'], dtype='object')

Furthermore, if I remove multiindex by removing "index_col=0", I still have the same keyerror when I'm printing df.loc['Symbol']

Printing df.head() gives

[image: pht]

Comment: Can you replace `print(df.loc['symbol'])` with just `print(df.loc)` and see what it print's out? Then update your question with the results?

Comment: yes, I edited the post @Oddity

Comment: use `df.columns` to get the columns' name.

Comment: what is the output of `print(df.head())`.

Comment: @Ferris and again, I updated the post, it looks like something is going wrong in the reading file, but i dont know what

Comment: use `df = df.reset_index()` to convert the index to a column.

Comment: @Ferris yes yes I know, but it also doesnt work, I tried it by simply removing index_col=0 while reading file, it doesnt change anything, key error still occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `df.loc['symbol']`.

use `df.loc[:, 'Symbol']` or `df['Symbol']` instead.

if `Symbol` is the df's index, then apply `df = df.reset_index()` first.

You can get more detail in pandas official guide [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).